# What are .EXE.IGNORE files and why are they on my windows machine

Tags: windows, chocolatey

I found a bunch of zero-length files with the extension .EXE.IGNORE on a few windows machines recently.

Their purpose and source was a unknown, so I dug into it some...

Answer (score 1):

It turns out these files .EXE.IGNORE are side-effects from installation of certain packages using the [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) package installer.   While I've concluded they aren't in themselves harmful, in a production environment it might suggests a need for better configuration control

There is a [bug opened for the Python package on Github](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey-coreteampackages/issues/249).

Comment: In a production environment, one should be quite wary of using packages they can not directly control. In other words, when most organizations use Chocolatey, they don't use the community repository packages without internalizing them. They typically build and host their own packages - see https://chocolatey.org/docs/community-packages-disclaimer for more information.